# How to render emoji's in with QGraphicsTextItem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

Here is the thing. I've created a little Qt chat application for my work office. It is only for lan connected clients. I implemented this by using QGraphicsTextItem for the messages inside bubbles which are a rounded rectancles.

To really complete it I need to add emojis to it. All chat-like applications have them. The thing is that I don't know how to implement them. I've read that they are part of the unicode standad. (the unicode codes for this link proves it http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), but I have no idea how to render it in a QGraphicsTextItem. Is it even possible?

I could do a very very manual labor of separating the user string and actually use multiple text items to render the parts fo the strings separated by emojis y and then the emoji themselves as a separate graphical entity, but I rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to do: the emojis are simply characters, you can copy-paste them from the "Brow" column in the [page you cited](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), just like you would any other character e.g. from this answer (including the emoji!). A sane compiler assumes that your source is UTF-8 encoded, as do most editors, so it will be transparent. If the relevant fonts are installed, it will just work.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/emoji-text-item-38000855
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   QGraphicsView view{&scene};
   QGraphicsTextItem item{QStringLiteral("I'm a happy . ")};
   scene.addItem(&item);
   view.ensureVisible(scene.sceneRect());
   view.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Yes that worked. I've just copied and pasted from the brow column into my applicaction and it worked. However it was way too small and looked frankly horrible. But that is another matter. Thank you.

Comment: @aarelovich You can change the font size for these characters by leveraging rich text, you can also select from alternate emoji fonts if you've got more than one.